# When scrolling the table, the color of the NavigationBar changes

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview, navigationbar

NavigationBar color changes when TableView scrolls. I don't know how to fix this problem. Tell me please.(UIKit)

Comment: This is standard in most apps. It's normal.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a default behavior for navigation bar in iOS 15+. To prevent this you can select navigation bar in storyboard and `check Standard & Scroll Edge` in attribute inspector, then change the background color in `Standard Appearance` and `Scroll Edge Appearances` section or see this image:
[Storyboard configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVhgz.png)

If you want to do it programatically you can call this code in viewDidLoad:

```
 let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
 appearance.backgroundColor = .blue
 navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
 navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

If you want to do it globally you can call this code in AppDelegate:

```
  let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
  appearance.backgroundColor = .red
  UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
  UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```